# In an ASP.Net LoginView, 2 sets of UserName and Password TextBoxes are displayed

Tags: asp.net, loginview

Using an ASP.Net LoginView, 2 sets of UserName and Password TextBoxes are displayed.

Using this markup, can you tell us how to only show 1 set of the UserName and Password TextBoxes from the AnonymousTemplate?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel 
    ID="UpdatePanelParentsSummary" 
    runat="server" 
    UpdateMode="Conditional">

    <ContentTemplate> 


        <div class="Menu">

            <asp:LoginView 
                ID="loginViewMain" 
                runat="server">

                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    <asp:LoginStatus 
                        ID="loginStatus" 
                        runat="server" />

                    <asp:Login runat="server" ID="login"></asp:Login>
                </AnonymousTemplate>

                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    <asp:LoginName 
                        ID="loginName" 
                        runat="server"
                        FormatString="Hello, {0}!<br/><br/> You have successfully<br/> logged onto the staff site." />

                    (<asp:LoginStatus ID="loginStatus" runat="server" />)

                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource 
                        id="KnowledgeAcademySiteMap" 
                        runat="server"
                        ShowStartingNode="false" />

                    <asp:TreeView 
                        id="TreeViewMain"
                        runat="server"
                        ExpandDepth="0"
                        OnTreeNodeExpanded="TreeViewMain_TreeNodeExpanded"
                        DataSourceID="KnowledgeAcademySiteMap">

                        <RootNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" />
                        <ParentNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" />
                        <LeafNodeStyle ImageUrl="/Images/book.png" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
                </LoggedInTemplate>

            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: is the '</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>' on the third line from the bottom meant to be there - doesnt seem to have a matching <asp:ContentPlaceHolder> tag further up?

Comment: Thanks. I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the markup shown, there should be only one `<asp:Login>` control displayed. There must be some other markup or code that is affecting this.

The best option at this point would be to debug the problem by adding some additional content that will help figure out where everything is coming from. For example, you could try the following:

1. Enable Tracing in the page by setting Trace=true in the @Page directive at the top of the ASPX file. That will render a graph of the control tree at the bottom of the page, which might help you figure out where the other Login control is.
2. Add some dummy markup immediately before and after the Login control that you see, such as putting the text BEGINBEGINBEGIN right before it, and ENDENDEND right after it. If you see that rendering once, then there's a different Login control coming from somewhere else. If you see it rendering twice, then something is causing the whole control to render twice, which must be coming from some custom code that is not being shown.
3. Start removing bits and pieces of the page to simplify it, until you figure out what is causing the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I found it. It was an extra login control in the Login.aspx file. I removed that control and now I have what I wanted which is 1 set of TextBoxes.